# Describe all solution of $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's start with the question: 
Let $A$ = 
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 5 & 1 & 4   \\
        3 & 15 & 3 & -12 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Describe all solutions of $A$x=$0$

Now here's where I get loss, the solution is asked in the following format :

$x = x2+x3+x4$

It seems like a very trivial question, yet I'm totally stuck. I get that both equations are the same since $R2 = R2 - 3R1$ Will give me $0x1 + 0x2 + 0x3 + 0x4 =0$ but I don't really know where to go from there

Comment: what do you mean with $R3 = R3 - 3R1$ ?
and what do you mean with $x = x2+x3+x4$ ? is it meant as $x_2$?

Comment: Hi. The rows are not the same as the sign for the last column is different.

Comment: Ohhh, that's why I get stuck. Good thing I added what I 'thought' I understood.

Comment: @supinf $R3 = R3 - 3R1$ probably denotes a row-operation.  I don't know about the second one.

Comment: i'm sorry I meant Row 2 - 3x Row 1 not Row 3. I've corrected the answer

Comment: If you subtract three times the first row from the second you don't obtain a zero row, the last term will be -24, which yields the equation $-24x_4 = 0 \Rightarrow x_4 = 0$

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry guys, I think I've tunnel vision this question I'll flag it to be deleted. Thanks for pointing my mistakes out I think I'll know where to go from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref(A)
=
\begin{bmatrix}1&5&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Also note that $\vec x$ satisfies $A\vec x=\vec 0$ if and only if $\rref(A)\vec x=\vec 0$. This means $A\vec x=\vec 0$ if and only if 
$$
\vec x=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-5\,x_2-x_3 \\
x_2\\
x_3\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
=
x_2
\begin{bmatrix}
-5\\1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
+x_3\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
If you're familiar with vector space lingo, then you could say that the the nullspace of $A$ is the two-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ spanned by
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
-5\\1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}&&
\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but what about x4?

Comment: To be honest I don't understand how you get x2 and x3 either :( I get stuck at the first form of it (-5x2-x4, x2, x3, 0) I don't know how to get from there to x2 + x3 + x4

Answer (score 1):

x is a column vector of 4 elements and by convention they are numbered / indexed like this : 
$$x = \left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{array}\right)$$

Now try and see what each row-multiplication between $A$ and $x$ becomes.